# include pygame in your program

Tags: include, pygame

I'm about to finish a program which uses Pygame, which means you would need to install Python and Pygame in order to run the game.  How can I include Python and Pygame in the program itself, or is there an easy way to make an installer for the game?

Comment: have you looked at `py2exe` or maybe `pygame2exe` (if you need it)

Comment: There are many ways of compiling programs into .exe's, the majority of which you can find ways to include third party things, like pygame, into them.  I would py2exe.  I tried it once and it went perfectly on the first try.

Comment: ok Thanks, now i know what to look for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`py2exe` seems to be a popular answer, and I would suggest looking into it as well. I would also suggest trying `pyinstaller`. The setup is a bit more involved, but the tutorials are great.

Answer (score 1):

Like PygameNerd said, I would suggest looking into py2exe. I wrote a game for a game jam and wanted to distribute it to people in my dorm. I used py2exe to load it up and distribute it pretty effortlessly (especially using Pygame).

Check out [the py2exe website](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) as well as [this link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules) on working with various modules in your package. I had dependencies with wxPython and used the latter guide to much success.