# Include pygame in Python package

Tags: python, pygame

Just to clear things up, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589724/include-pygame-in-your-programm` didn't work, as I have a Mac.

Ok. Now that's over, I can begin.

I'm making a game in python and I'm using the `pygame` module. The problem is, the vast majority of people don't already have pygame.

How do I include pygame module, without people having to install pygame manually, without using `py2app` or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Pygame module or a copy of it in a folder alongside the program so that when someone downloads your game, they download Pygame with it. You may be able to use the OS module to find the path of Pygame ( if needed ) and import it from that. Hope this helps.

Use this thread to help you out with finding the module path. 
[How to retrieve a module's path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path/248862#248862)